# loop to add data from a different datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

My DataTable which I want to call to my 2nd table:

First table:

```
 Dim table As New DataTable

 ' columns in the DataTable.
 table.Columns.Add("Monday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
 table.Columns.Add("Tuesday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
 table.Columns.Add("Wednesday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
 table.Columns.Add("Thursday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
 table.Columns.Add("Friday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
 '  rows with those columns filled in the DataTable.
 table.Rows.Add(1, 2005, 2000, 4000, 34)
 table.Rows.Add(2, 3024, 2343, 2342, 12)
 table.Rows.Add(3, 2320, 9890, 1278, 2)
```

now this is my 2nd table which i need to loop:

** not finished, want to add 1 from table to table2, in the first row.**

```
   Dim table2 As New DataTable


    ' columns in the DataTable.
    table2.Columns.Add("one", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table2.Columns.Add("two", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))

    table2.Rows.Add()  *** add 1 (from monday) from first table**** ??
    table2.Rows.Add()
    table2.Rows.Add()
    table2.Rows.Add()
```

Using the table2, how can i link the information of Monday, to add in one in table 2, i will need a loop i think to call it.

In the first table, i want 1 that is in monday to show in "one" which is in the 2nd table, table2.

For alex:

```
 Monday    Tuesday    Wed
 10           40       9
 20           50       6
 30           70       4
```

Comment: in the first table, i want 1 that is in monday to show in "one" which is in the 2nd table, table2..

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is not clear enough. What do you want to do with you table 2 ? Do you have a concrete example of what you want to get once you added table 2 in table 1 ?

Comment: yeah, that is under monday in table. to be added in table2, in the column one.

Comment: i want to add 1 that is in column monday in table, to table2, column one. i think some loop is required to get it from table.

Comment: that doesnt add the 1 that is under monday

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to **add the first column value** of `Table1` to your `Table2`

```
For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
    table2.Rows.Add(row(0)) 'This will add the first column value of Table1 to the first column of Table2

    'Here's how the index works:
    'table.Rows.Add(1, 2005, 2000, 4000, 34)
    'row(0) = 1
    'row(1) = 2005
    'row(2) = 2000
    'row(3) = 4000
    'row(4) = 34
Next
```

To add values to your two columns in Table2 you would do this:

```
For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
    table2.Rows.Add({row(0), row(1)})

    'If I take your second example:
     Monday    Tuesday    Wed
     10           40       9
     20           50       6
     30           70       4

    'The first iteration through Table1 will add (10,40)
    'The second iteration through Table1 will add (20,50)
    'And so on...
Next
```

Comment: You change the index from 0 to 1 ... to 4

Comment: If "apple" is in the first column of table one, you would still do `table2.Rows.Add(row(0))`

Comment: ooh, so if apple was 2nd in the column, it would be . table2.Rows.Add(row(2))

Comment: If "apple" would be in the second column of table1, then it would be table2.Rows.Add(row(1)) ... The indexes are zero-based.

Comment: ok cool, so based on my table, how would i call column tuesday, 2005 from table 1 to table2

Comment: To get the value of 2005 from the column Tuesday in table1 to table2, you would do `table2.Rows.Add(row(1))`. Keep in mind everything that is `row(index)` is from the foreach example.

Comment: but isnt that the same as getting that from monday, how do you differentiate from coulmn monday and tuesday, because ideally you can use table2.Rows.Add(row(1)) but is this getting the monday or tuesday coulmn

Comment: You have 5 columns (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday & Friday). Each of those columns have an index (an index is zero-based, meaning it starts at 0 instead of 1). `Monday = 0, Tuesday = 1, Wednesday = 2, Thursday = 3, Friday = 4`

Comment: yeah but under monday, there are 5 items, 1,2,3,4,5. isnt that also 
1= 1, 2=2 etc... so it clashes

Comment: No, that's the meaing of "Zero-based" indexes. You have 5 items, but the indexes start at zero ... 0,1,2,3,4 = 5 items.